# Как изменить проверку кода в Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row) {?>
            <input id="sort_order_<?php echo $row; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Нетбинс говорит, что мол плохое значение для айди, поскольку у данного атрибута не должно быть пустых мест (whitespaces). Тоже самое происходит с name. Подскажите, где это можно поправить?

Comment: навряд ли вы сможете вмешаться в стандарты заложенные в чужую ide , обычно только полностью проверку отключить разрешают.

Comment: Фигня в том что на работе не ругается, версии и набор плагинов одинаковые

Comment: <?php foreach($rows as $row) echo "<input id=\"sort_order_$row\">"; ?>

Comment: @Sergey не рассматривайте частные случаи.

Comment: @iyaki а операционные системы одинаковые? если да тогда копируйте настройки из версии на работе. возможно там другой уровень проверки (наверно его можно изменить в настройках IDE).

Comment: <?php foreach($rows as $row) {?>
            <input id="sort_order_<?=$row?>">
<?php } ?>

Comment: @Sergey на короткую запись реагирует так же, а вывод через эхо жутко не удобен данный пример упрощен для наглядности

Comment: Может на работе отключено предупреждение. Настраивается в сервис/параметры/редактор/подсказки. Ну и при редактировании можно отключить (включить обратно только в настройках). И ещё убедиться, что файл открыт в редакторе php, а не простого html. Проверить обновления

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в определении файла.
Если кто с таким столкнется решается так: Сервис/Параметры/Разное/Файлы

Расширение файла: tpl

Связанный тип файла (MIME): text/5-php

Стоял text/html - он и ругался

Забавно, что перенос настроек на это по какой то причине не повлиял.